# Кодировка ответа ajaxa и кодировка страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, кодировка, java, javascript

День добрый!

Ситуация такая: есть ajax запрос от jquery, который берет нечто и вставляет это в страницу. 
Есть эта самая страница со своей некоей кодировкой.

Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы возвращаемый аяксом ответ всегда соответствовал кодировке страницы? (для избежания проблем с показом русских символов)

То есть сделать так:

1. взять значение `charset` из мета-тэга
2. передать его в ajax-запросе на сервер
3. на сервере поставить нужную кодировку в заголовок ответа

Вопрос: нормальный ли это способ? 
Как лучше определять кодировку запрашивающей сервер страницы: передавать вручную то, что узнали, через js или смотреть заголовки запроса или еще что?

Comment: Если у Вас java - надо было в метках указать ;)
исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аякс работает с utf8, iconv при ответе и при отправке, и все будет сладко, а еще лучше переходить полностью на utf8, и головняка такого рода не будет... правда появится другой головняк.

Comment: Интересно узнать, какая появится головная боль при полном переходе на utf8?

Comment: Не работают обычные функции типа substr, нужно юзать mb_substr, ну аналогично с другими строковыми функциями, все не проверял :)

Comment: Если Аякс вернет utf8, а страница в windows-1251, то я получу проблему. Вопрос был в том как это лучше исправить, если страницу изменить нельзя.

Comment: Я Вам ответил:

[iconv][1]


  [1]: http://ua.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

Comment: <b>OZIM</b> - написано вернет, каким образом получение аякса можно обрабатывать сервером?О_о<br>
Получать данные и сразу же пулять на еще один скрипт чтобы перегнать через iconv? :D

Comment: Может и я чего то не понимаю..
Итак: страница в win-1251 (index.php), в ней форма для отправки запроса на некий файл (ajax.php), с помощью той же jquery шлем на него запрос, и в этом файле с помощью iconv формируем строку в utf
>$requestvar=iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $requestvar);

затем ajax.php дает нам ответ, мы его переводим обратно в win-1251
>$response=iconv( 'utf-8', 'windows-1251', $response);

и получаем ответ с помощью javascript кода в файле index.php

Comment: Тогда у меня вопрос - какой смысл этого преобразования, сами подумайте что вы написали...<br>
Грубо вы добавили 2 гирьки одинакового веса на весы с разных сторон, т.е. выполнили лишнее действие.<br>
Может мне пора спать, но помоему это не решение проблемы utf-8, какая разница скрипту в какой кодировке работать, ну вот реально.<br>
Если нам приходит cp1251 и мы смогли его коректно обработать и отдать, то смысла в этих действиях нет, я конечно уже с год не в теме(я о cp1251), но помоему тут очевидно что смысла в этих операциях нет абсолютно никакого...<br>
Поправьте если ересь написал ^^

Comment: Есть смысл, нет смысла, это решение помогло ТС или нет, вот что главное?..
мы же не соревнуемся6 у кого решение будет ну самое классное и мего умное, я вот знаю такое, и благополучно его использовал, так как в ajax.php придут кракозябры, а не нормальная строка, и если не повешать вторую гирьку - придут кракозябры оттуда..

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за дискуссию! Жаль что я не сделал ряд уточнений.
1) у меня вообще не php, а java. но это не важно, просто iconv не поможет. но если мы знаем нужную нам кодировку, то закодировать строку ответа сервера не проблема любым языком.
2) у меня все еще проще: на сервер достаточно передать запрос латинскими буквами, а вот ответ будет кириллица. в какой кодировке она будет? должна быть в той же, что и страница, отправившая запрос.

Comment: В итоге я споткнулся на этапе передачи кодировки на сервер. Я хочу сделать это в заголовках аякс-запроса jquery.ajax, но не получается. Пробую делать это через параметр contentType : "windows-1251" или параметр-функцию beforeSend(request) {request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript; charset: windows-1251")}, но отправляемый запрос не содержит соотв. заголовка. Если же он будет, то я легко выдам ответ сервером в переданной таким образом кодировке. Можно, конечно, в аттрибут кодировку поместить, но логичнее в header.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript всегда оперирует (должен оперировать, по крайней мере) с текстом в utf